# How to call same function from different places using different parameters in javascript and still retain old values of variables of that function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular

I have following code in my geolocation program.

When user allows device to get the geolocation, the `geolocation()` function  gets called and the `geolocation` function again propagates the `successPosition` function with `position` object that gives latitude and longitude. Inside the `successPosition` function I also need other variable called `btype` (Blood type) since I am developing a program to find nearest blood doners.

So in the past I tried to ask user which blood type to search using javascript `prompt` method but using that approach user would have to manually type the blood type but what I want is to let user select the type from dropdown. But If I create a form and ask user the type and pass object to `SuccessPosition` function, the `position` object becomes undefined - this is because this time we are only passing `btype` and we dont have `position`. And when `position` object gets passed the another variable `btype` is undefined.

Please tell me what is the best approach to solve the problem.

```
geolocation: function() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.successPosition, this.failurePosition, {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeout: 3000,
      maximumAge: 4000
    });

  } else {
    return (false);
  }
},
successPosition: function(position) {
  self.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  self.longitude = position.coords.longitude;

  //self.btype = btype;

  self.partial_url = ("/users?utf8=✓&longitude=" + (self.longitude) 
                   + "&latitude=" + (self.latitude)
                   + "&btype=" + encodeURIComponent(self.btype));

  window.location = self.partial_url;

}
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to make your code fit within the bounds of the box so that people viewing it don't have to scroll so much.

Comment: Are you using services as singletons? Use of services should allow you to decouple btype from location

Answer (score 0):

Your `successPosition` function doesn't have to be responsible for setting the `window.location` immediately. I think the simplest thing in your case would be to have `successPosition` trigger the form which allows the user to select their blood type, and have an event listener bound to the form element which calls something like `setWindowLocation` with the blood type when the user selects one. Now you'll have your geolocation and your blood type.